# Why is "amd" written in many installers?

Tags: x86-64, intel, amd-processor

I have seen many installers like that of Python and Ubuntu which has "amd" on them. Why is that so? Can I run those programs on my laptop having intel cpu? Please explain to me in detail. Thanks :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#AMD64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just AMD, it's AMD64.

Linux/gcc's names for [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) architectures are: i386 for 32bit, and amd64 for 64bit.

AMD designed x86-64, and amd64 existed as a name for it before Intel's first ia-32e CPUs were released.  (Yes, Intel made up their own name for it.  Also note that ia-64 is Itanium, not x86-64.)

(See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for vendor manuals and assembly-language info).

Answer (score 0):

You get your answer from the following excerpt from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64).

> x86-64 (also known as x64, x86_64 and AMD64) is the 64-bit version of
>   the x86 instruction set. It supports vastly larger amounts
>   (theoretically, 264 bytes or 16 exbibytes) of virtual memory and
>   physical memory than is possible on its 32-bit predecessors, allowing
>   programs to store larger amounts of data in memory.